# How to add JPanel Components on top of a painted background

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I want to be able to change one of my JPanel background to a image I created and still add components on top of it, however they are not showing up.

```
package userInterface;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial") public class BoardPanel extends JPanel {

  private Image img;

  public BoardPanel() {
    img = new ImageIcon("images/board.png").getImage();
    JButton button = new JButton("TEST ME");
    add(button);

    Dimension size = new Dimension(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null));
    setPreferredSize(size);
    setMinimumSize(size);
    setMaximumSize(size);
    setSize(size);
    setLayout(null);
  }

  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for non-visibility of `JButton` on the `JPanel` is that you are setting the layout of the `JPanel` to be `null` :

```
setLayout(null);
```

Setting layout to be `null` makes you to set the location of the components explicitly which is also very bad practice. You should instead remove that line and let the internal `layout` of the `Swing` to do its work gracefully. 
*As side note I would emphasize on the point that whenever you are overriding the `paintComponent` method , the first statement of this method must be `super.paintComponent(g)`*

Comment: override getPreferredSize for JPanel :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you overwrite `paintComponent(Graphics g)`, always remember to call `super.paintComponent(g)` first.
That way everything which would normally be painted will be painted as well.